# Out-of-Process Observer in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, observer-pattern, message

I am writing a file manager ([FileTracker](http://code.google.com/p/filetracker/)) and would like to off-load all the I/O to an out-of-process service that simply messages the UI when it needs to.

The only problem is: I don't know how. Well, more specifically, I don't know if my solution is the better solution.

I am thinking of opening a socket and communicating that way. Another approach would be to use a self-hosted WCF service, but then I'd be restricted to callbacks. I'm not convinced there isn't already some level of message pump I could reuse in Windows. I don't want to go so far as to require MSMQ for a file manager but I'm sure there's a way to message between applications.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try searching for Inter-Process Communication (IPC)?

Comment: In similar need I used [WCF with netpipe binding](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#q=wcf+netpipe), which is form of IPC in Windows

Comment: Why out of process ? Are worker and I/O threads not enough ?

Comment: Have a look at http://hangfire.io

Comment: @schglurps: I want to be able to recover from long-running dirs and I want to be able to release any memory that gets allocated. One of the reasons I started writing this is because I had a dir where I worked that was over 3500 entries and caused an "out of memory" for windows File Manager.

Comment: @TomRedfern: It looks like Hangfire is for ASP and this is a WinForms app (I'm doing a lot of the painting myself). Also, it has the fire-and-forget but what about reacting to FileWatchers when the dir changes?

Comment: There are lots of ways to message between applications in Windows. Asking which one is best for your needs is too broad, especially when there's basically no real context for anyone to base an answer on.